HTTP Proxy behind Reverse Proxy
I have an Ubuntu server behind a Reverse Proxy server due to some security reasons. I want to access this Ubuntu server through SSH and VNC, and also access some other services hosted on this server. However, I do not have the permissions to modify any firewall configurations on the Reverse Proxy server. All I have access to are the HTTP and HTTPS reverse proxy, which can only be used to reach web pages hosted by my Ubuntu Apache service.
Is there a way for me to achieve this without changing the firewall settings on the Reverse Proxy server? Are there any alternative methods or configurations I can employ to access my Ubuntu server and its services securely?
What I have tried:
I don't have much experience running an HTTP server. The only way I've tried is by setting up a Caddy HTTP proxy service and using a VPN such as OpenVPN to connect to my Ubuntu server through the HTTP proxy. However, I've encountered an issue where I'm unable to connect to the HTTP proxy successfully. I'm not sure what the reason is, as I can connect to the HTTP proxy using my Ubuntu server and other computers on the same LAN:

I've checked the Caddy configuration file and ensured that the HTTP proxy settings are correct. I'm also able to connect to the VPN successfully through my Ubuntu server. However, when I try to connect to the HTTP proxy from other computers through reverse proxy , it doesn't work,  and the Caddy log file doesn't even have connect log.

I think maybe the reverse proxy server block http proxy, is there any other way to achieve my goals or some vpn using http/https protocol?

So to clarify, you do not have direct access to the server and all the access you have is via a proxy that can only forward traffic to ports 80 and 443 and you are unable to modify any of the proxy configuration?  Other than writing a web app that behaves like a terminal (e.g. something that takes input from a form and forward them to a shell) then I don't think there's much more that you can do.

@apokryfos Wow, your response was lightning fast! Thank you very much for your prompt reply! In that case, I'll go find a web app option on github.
